# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Ayuda estoy en el proceso de creación de un blog y al tratar de acceder al index
me sale en pantalla que hubo un error con la función prepare() on null, no entiendo porque porfa ayuda :( abajo cree la conexión

```php
    function conexion($bd_config){
        try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass']);
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $conexion;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Aquí definí los datos de la Base de datos

```php
<?php

define('RUTA', 'http://localhost/curso/Practicas/PracticaBlog/');

$bd_config = array(
    'basedatos' => 'blog',
    'usuario' => 'root',
    'pass' => ''
);

$blog_config = array(
    'post_por_pagina'=> '2',
    'carpeta_imagenes' => 'imagenes/'
);

$blog_admin = array(
    'usuario' => 'Nicolas',
    'password' => '456'
);

?>
```

aquí abajo llamo la conexión

```
<?php 

require 'admin/config.php'; 

require 'functions.php';


if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: Error.php');
}

$posts = obtener_post($blog_config['post_por_pagina'],$conexion);

if (!$posts) {
    header('Location: Error.php');
}

require 'views/index.view.php';

 ?>
```

Si hacen falta mas detalles comentenlo y los pondré, gracias buen dia :,D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, el problema era que no estaba llamando la conexión en el ultimo código que mostré, aun así gracias a todos.